# ifthen with different format numbers

Tags: conditionals

I want to compare the number with different format, but do not get the desired result.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{numprint}
\npthousandsep{,}
\npdecimalsign{.}
\nprounddigits{2}

\newcommand{\dotnumber}{1200.00}
\newcommand{\nodotnumber}{1200}

\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\numprint{\dotnumber}}{\numprint{\nodotnumber}}}{true}{false}\\
\numprint{\dotnumber}\\
\numprint{\nodotnumber}\\
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:
[image: result]

What is the problem there? Are there any methods to get the result to be true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not comparing two numbers, but the set of instructions to *print* them; so the test cannot succeed.

This is a job for `expl3` and its floating point module.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{numprint}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\numcompare}{O{=}mmmm}
 {
  \fp_compare:nTF { #2 #1 #3 } { #4 } { #5 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\npthousandsep{,}
\npdecimalsign{.}
\nprounddigits{2}

\newcommand{\dotnumber}{1200.00}
\newcommand{\nodotnumber}{1200}

\begin{document}

\numcompare{\dotnumber}{\nodotnumber}{true}{false}

\numprint{\dotnumber}

\numprint{\nodotnumber}

Expected: true; true, true, false

\numcompare{1.2e2}{120}{true}{false};
\numcompare[>]{10}{9}{true}{false};
\numcompare[>=]{10}{10}{true}{false};
\numcompare[<]{10}{9}{true}{false}

\end{document}
```

The function `\fp_compare:nTF` performs the test on the supplied numbers (and the supplied relation sign, if the default `=` is not wanted); the numbers should be in a format according to IEEE standards for floating points.

[image]

Comment: For either the true or false case, how to make any of them accept paragraphs with empty lines? I get this error `Paragraph ended before \numcompare  was complete.`

Comment: @diaa The argument list should be `O{=}mm+m+m` where the `+` prefix denotes an argument that can contain `\par`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do testing the part before dot and the part after dot separately.

**Edit** If you need to do other tests (`<` or `>`, not only `=`), then the "after-dot" part must be re-calculated using `\tnC` macro. Zeros are appended to nine digits in total by this macro. If there are more than nine digits in the "after-dot" part then the rest is simply ignored. So, exact calculation is possible to nine digits after decimal dot only. This is due to the maximal integer in TeX is cca 2*10^9. If you need more exact calculation then use `\input apnum` or some similar.

```
\newif\iftestnumber
\def\testnumbers#1#2#3#4{%
   \edef\tmpA{\expandafter\tnA#1.;}\edef\tmpB{\expandafter\tnA#3.;}%
   \edef\tmpAA{\expandafter\tnAA#1.;}\edef\tmpBB{\expandafter\tnAA#3.;}%
   \def\tmp{}\expandafter\tnC\tmpAA!;000000000!;\let\tmpAA=\tmp
   \def\tmp{}\expandafter\tnC\tmpBB!;000000000!;\let\tmpBB=\tmp
   \testnumberfalse
   \ifx=#2\ifnum\tmpA=\tmpB\space \ifnum\tmpAA=\tmpBB\space \testnumbertrue\fi\fi
   \else \ifnum\tmpA#2\tmpB\space \testnumbertrue
         \else \ifnum\tmpA=\tmpB\space \ifnum\tmpAA#2\tmpBB\space \testnumbertrue
   \fi   \fi
   \iftestnumber
}
\def\tnA#1.#2;{\ifx;#1;0\else#1\fi}
\def\tnAA#1.#2;{\ifx;#2;0\else \tnA#2;\fi}
\def\tnC#1#2;#3#4;{\ifx!#3\def\next##1;##2;{}\else
   \ifx!#1\edef\tmp{\tmp#3}\def\next{\tnC!}%
   \else\edef\tmp{\tmp#1}\let\next=\tnC\fi\fi
   \next#2;#4;%
}

\def\dotnumber{1200.00}
\def\nodotnumber{1200}

\testnumbers \dotnumber=\nodotnumber \iftrue True\else False\fi

\testnumbers {2.009} < {2.012} \iftrue True\else False\fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dimension :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{numprint}
\npthousandsep{,}
\npdecimalsign{.}
\nprounddigits{2}

\newcommand{\dotnumber}{1200.00}
\newcommand{\nodotnumber}{1200}

\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\numprint{\dotnumber}}{\numprint{\nodotnumber}}}{true}{false}\\
\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\dotnumber pt=\nodotnumber pt}}{true}{false}\\
\numprint{\dotnumber}\\
\numprint{\nodotnumber}\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem of this method is that large number is not allowed, or the LaTeX will show errors. Any solution?

Comment: @Joe Could you show an example ?

Comment: For example, 120000